# Regex pattern to get only particular part from List of String

Tags: java, regex

As i am new to Regex pattern i want to extract particular part from below mentioned List of string and want to store it in Map as key value pair.

Example:

```
List<String> ref3Path = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ref3Path.add("s3://REF3/ca209_040/ahshd.csv");
ref3Path.add("s3://REF3/ca209_040/grren.csv");
ref3Path.add("s3://REF3/ca209_030/aestyyuae.csv");
```

i want only **ca209_040** and **aesae.csv** from the above list and want to store in Map.

Below is the code for I am writing to compare list and map:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    MultiValuedMap<String, String> studyDomain = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();
    List<String> ref3Path = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    studyDomain.put("ca209_040", "czvv.csv");
    studyDomain.put("ca209_040", "efe.csv");
    studyDomain.put("ca209_030", "efef.csv");
    studyDomain.put("ca209_030", "hhhjd.csv");
    studyDomain.put("ca209_020", "rr.csv");
    studyDomain.put("ca209_020", "eghh.csv");

    ref3Path.add("s3://REF3/ca209_040/jlkjl.csv");
    ref3Path.add("s3://REF3/ca209_040/aesaehkhk.csv");
    ref3Path.add("s3://REF3/ca209_030/aesaedhd.csv");
    ref3Path.add("null");
    ref3Path.add("s3://REF3/ca209_020/aedae.csv");
    ref3Path.add("s3://REF3/ca209_020/aeqwee.csv");

    log.info("List of inbox: " +studyDomain);
    log.info("List of ref3 :" +ref3Path);

    rule1(studyDomain,ref3Path);
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the regex you want is `s3://REF3/(\w+)/(\w+\.\w+)` and then put the first group as key and the second group as value.

Comment: Can you apply it and show me here as I don't know how to use regex.

Comment: [No](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+regex)

Comment: That is not really a question; it's more like an request to write the code. Please try the [tour]... and then maybe rephrase the question.

Comment: Why is this question labeled 'scala'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with simple `split` function. Regex pattern is overkill

Note: check for boundary conditions

```
scala> val arr = "s3://REF3/ca209_040/aesae.csv".split('/')
arr: Array[String] = Array(s3:, "", REF3, ca209_040, aesae.csv)

scala> arr(3)
res2: String = ca209_040

scala> arr(4)
res3: String = aesae.csv
```

## In Java

Note: check for boundary conditions

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] s) {
        String[] args = "s3://REF3/ca209_040/aesae.csv".split("/");
        System.out.println(args[3] + " ,  " + args[4]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ShwetaSharma Added Java code . Now just iterate on each element of list and then split and then  convert it into Map. `args[3]` is your map key and `args[4]` is you map value

Comment: It will split the `String` correctly, but there will be an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when parsing `ref3Path.add("null");`. This value is added in the code of the question.